# send json object from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to send JSON object from Javascript/Jquery to PHP and I am getting and error msg in my console. What am I doing wrong. I am new to JS and PHP.

**JQuery file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var flickr = {'action': 'Flickr', 'get':'getPublicPhotos'};
    // console.log(typeof(flickr));
    var makeFlickrCall = function(flickrObj){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../phpincl/apiConnect.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: flickrObj
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
    };

    makeFlickrCall(flickr);
});
```

**PHP file**

```php
<?php       
    $obj = $_POST['data'];
    // print_r($obj);
    return $obj;
?>
```

Comment: the console.log error .fail and .always msg is displayed on my console window.

Comment: try `print_r($_POST)` to see the result.

Comment: this suggests that you want to send the variable `flickrObj` as data, you need to make that a global variable,what is in that?

Comment: This is my variable flickr = {'action': 'Flickr', 'get':'getPublicPhotos'};

Comment: @AmitGarg, the print_r displays the object like this. 
"Array\n(\n    [action] => Flickr\n    [get] => getPublicPhotos\n)\n"

Comment: My answer below should work flawlessly. Try it!! :)

Comment: You have to use `$_POST['action']` to get the value of action and `$_POST['get']` to get the value of get. if you just want to return it the `echo json_encode($_POST);`.

Comment: @AmitGarg, what if I want to store the post in $obj = $_POST['data'] instead of 2 variables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Excellent answer by Phil, however since the OP title says

> send json object from javascript (**not jQuery** ) to php

this is how to do it with (vanilla) javascript, in case it helps somebody looking for this method:

```
var jsondata;
var flickr = {'action': 'Flickr', 'get':'getPublicPhotos'};
var data = JSON.stringify(flickr);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "../phpincl/apiConnect.php", !0);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(data);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        // in case we reply back from server
        jsondata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(jsondata);
    }
}
```

**Notice** we still need to convert the server's response into a javascript *object* using `JSON.parse()`

Now, on the server side (based on Phil's answer) if you are sending back a response to the client, you could do:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_decode = json_decode($json, true); 
$json_encode = json_encode($json_decode);
echo $json_encode;
```

**NOTE**:

The reason behind decoding first and then encoding back the raw json input is to properly *escape* slashes in (possible) URLs within the data, e.g.

`json_encode` will convert this URL

```
http://example.com
```

into

```
http:\/\/example.com
```

... which is not the case in the OP but useful in some other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the response JFK, My title does say Javascript but the I've specified Javascript/Jquery in the description.

Comment: @Vish : no problem, I was just providing a way to do it with javascript only in case somebody doesn't want to include jQuery

Comment: appreciate your effort and I'm happy to know both ways to tackle the problem :)

Answer (score 10):

The standard jQuery `.ajax()` method uses the `data` property to create an *x-www-form-urlencoded* string to pass in the request body. Something like this

```
action=Flickr&get=getPublicPhotos
```

Therefore, your PHP script should not look for `$_POST['data']` but instead, `$_POST['action']` and `$_POST['get']`.

If you want to send a raw JSON data payload to PHP, then do the following...

Set the AJAX `contentType` parameter to `application/json` and send a *stringified* version of your JSON object as the `data` payload, eg

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../phpincl/apiConnect.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(flickrObj),
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Your PHP script would then read the data payload from the `php://input` stream, eg

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

You can then parse this into a PHP object or array...

```
$dataObject = json_decode($json);
$dataArray = json_decode($json, true);
```

And, if you're just wanting to echo it back to the client..

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

// unmodified
echo $json;

// or if you've made changes to say $dataArray
echo json_encode($dataArray);
```

Comment: what do I need to do to make the post work $_POST['data'] and return the object back to javascript?

Comment: @Phil Very helpful answer, can I make the php send back execution progress **several times** of whats going on at the moment?, cause my php execution is too long.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
makeFlickrCall( { data: JSON.stringify( flickr )} );
```

Instead of

```
makeFlickrCall(flickr);
```

Your server-side script should receive your JSON as follows:

```
data="{"action":"Flickr","get":"getPublicPhotos"}"
```