# How to post JSON from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I encoded an array into JSON in javascript:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(cVal);
```

And here is my ajaxrequest object:

```
function ajaxRequest(url, method, data, asynch, responseHandler){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open(method, url, asynch);
if (method == "POST")
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
        responseHandler(request.responseText);
        }
    }
};
request.send(data);
}
```

and I send the json to php with this ajaxrequset:

```
ajaxRequest("setOrder.php","POST", data , true , dosetOrder);
```

in php side:

```
$array=$_POST['data'];
```

but system says that the data in a undefined index in php

Comment: change request header content type to json and what is the problem you are getting ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599595/send-json-data-from-javascript-to-php   decode your json in php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750661/send-json-object-from-javascript-to-php

Comment: What is the output of this on PHP? print_r($_POST);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Create an object and stringify to json

```
var data = {};
data["username"] = username;
data["password"] = password;
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

## Send it to your endpoint

```
function ajaxRequest(url, method, data, asynch, responseHandler){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open(method, url, asynch);
  if (method == "POST")
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json"); 
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      if (request.status == 200) {
        responseHandler(request.responseText);
      }
    }
    request.send(data);
}
```

## decode it at your endpoint

### plain PHP

```
$body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
echo $body["username"];
```

### Slim Framework PHP

```
//example with Slim PHP framework
$body = json_decode($app->request->getBody(), true);
echo $body["username"];
```

Comment: Which crystal ball told you about `$app->...` in OP's code?

Comment: it's an example using Slim PHP framework as the code comment tells you, I only tried to show how you get the values from your parsed object.

Comment: I added a plain php example to make it more general.