# Ajax error: function called even when request status is 200

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my Ajax Call code:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    cache: false,
    data: { json : JSON.stringify({
        name:name,
        email:email,
        password:password
    })},
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(){
        alert('request successful');
    },

    error: function(){
        alert('error occured');
    }

});
```

The request status is 200 but the error function is called all the time.

Does anyone know,

- why is that?
- how can I fix it?

Comment: This can occur if the request works, but deserialisation fails. If you actually debug this using the console and the parameters passed to the `error` handler function you can get the error message to diagnose.

Comment: Can you show response you are getting? Seems you are not setting response in json format. You don't need to use `JSON.stringify` in data of Ajax call

Comment: @PankajMakwana *"You don't need to use `JSON.stringify` in data of Ajax call"* <- they do if they want to post a JSON string value for the `json` field.

Comment: @Phil well spotted, although if that was in the OP's production code then the request wouldn't be made due to the syntax error

Comment: The request is working fine, because the data is passed to `ajax.php` and being saved in database properly. In `ajax.php`, I am decoding json object like this: `$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);` And there is no error in console. @PankajMakwana what do I use to make json object?

Comment: @Alena given your JS code, it should be `$data = json_decode($_POST['json'])`

Comment: @Alena you can do like this `{        name:name,        email:email,        password:password    }` on php side you can use `$_POST['email']`

Comment: The *typical* way to POST JSON from jQuery to PHP is like this ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750707/283366

Comment: Can you please let me know the advantage of `JSON.stringify` in above question? @Phil

Comment: @PankajMakwana OP is expecting JSON posted to `ajax.php` in the "json" field. The request payload would look like `json=%7B%22name%22%3A%22some%20name%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22me%40example.com%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22hunter2%22%7D`. In PHP, they can then use `json_decode($_POST['json'])`. It's not necessarily the way [I would do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750707/283366) but there's nothing particularly wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: @Alena though you have suggested right way. PankajMakwana is very much right. In your code it is like you are encoding and decoding string without any kind of need. It seems like you want to choose long route even when you have safe shortcut.

Comment: @Phil getting undefined index `json_decode($_POST['json'])` if the data is in this format: `json=%7B%22name%22%3A%22some%20name....` BUT it works for this format:  `json={"name":"some name",....` Do you know, what's wrong? I have tried to set JSON header in php file but same issue.

Comment: @Alena did you have a look at the link I posted earlier about the typical way to send JSON from JS to PHP? You appear to be making this more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: @Phil I check that link and understand it now. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, the problem is in this line: `dataType: 'json',` Because it is expecting Json response and you are sending html or text text response. Let's take a look at **definitions** first:

- **JSON.stringify** turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.
- **contentType** is the header sent to the server, specifying a particular format.
- **dataType** is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect.

**Examples:**

If you're posting something like: `{"name":"John Doe"}` and expecting back: `{"success":true}`

Then you should have:

```
var data = {"name":"John Doe"};
dataType : "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data : JSON.stringify(data),
```

For More Details: [Check jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**Solution 1:** (tested)

- Just remove `dataType: 'json',` line and let jQuery decide data type. (it does pretty good job in identifying) OR Make sure to use correct dataType on both sides (client and server)

**Solution 2:** (tested)

**jQuery:**

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    dataType : "html", //assuming you need html response like '<div>Success</div>'
                       //Common types: html, xml, json & text
    cache: false,
    data: { json : encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
        name:name,
        email:email,
        password:password
    }))},


    success: function(){
        alert('request successful');
    },

    error: function(){
        alert('error occured');
    }

});
```

**PHP:**

```
$json_data = json_decode(urldecode($_POST['json']));
//now $json_data variable has decoded JSON data 
echo $json_data->name;
```

**Solution 3:** (not tested)

**Send JSON object** by setting `contentType`: like

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

then read raw input using `php://input` (**NOTE**: $`_POST` won't work here)

**Here's How:**

- Set Content Type in PHP file `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');`
- Get Data `$input = file_get_contents('php://input');`
- Decode data `$decoded_input = urldecode($input);`
- Finally, decode it as JSON object `$data = json_decode($input);`

Comment: a) You don't need to use `encodeURIComponent` in jQuery, it does that for you so you'd just end up double encoding the data. b) You should **never** have to use `urldecode` on a `$_POST` or  `$_GET` property. Any data from the request has already been decoded

Comment: @Phil maybe you are right. But the data was going on server like a json string. So, I add `encodeURIComponent` to encode and on server side the data was not decoded so I used `urldecode` BTW, I am not sure if OP wants encoding or not.

Comment: @Atlas_Gondal this is what I was looking for. Bundle of thanks :)