# Send normal variables along with mulitdimensional array to AJAX call to PHP

Tags: ajax

I'm sending some variables to AJAX call with POST method to PHP file as below -

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:  "sendEmail.php",
data: {
       'v1':mailto,
       'v2':pname,
       'v3':ptype
},
```

Now in addition to this, I've some data as below -
DataArray = {"name",value1, value2},{"name",value1, value2},{"name",value1, value2}.

How can I send above array (array of array objects) in above AJAX call. Also how can I get array in PHP file.

Any inputs will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `DataArray` doesn't look like any valid kind of JS data structure. Are you missing `[...]`?

Comment: This is a little too broad to answer properly. My advice would be to POST JSON data to your PHP script. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750707/283366

Comment: @ Phil - yes, I'm missing exact syntax actually.

Comment: Serialize the form data and send https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174312/7296317 Hope this link helps :)