# How to pass JS sessionStorage data to an email being sent out with PhpMailer?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

It seems to me that this is purely a logic problem.

I have a little app online in which a visitor provides some input that is handled with javascript and later enters their email address and the app sends the results to their email.

My question is this: 
How can one inject these javascript results from Javascript with the sessionStorage.getItem("string"); to be included in the HTML content of the email being sent out with PHPMailer?

Is it even possible to draw that sessionStorage information with PHP?

First time using PHP, so please explain it like I'm five.

Tried processing the javascript within the HTML content of the PHP email and tried pre-processing it. Nope.

Anyone care to think along?

```
function prepEmail() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("activity", swimming);
};


sessionStorage.getItem("activity"); => PHPMailer
```

Comment: Just send the sessionStorage object using JS to php. You can use any format for sending, eg: json format or whatever suits your design.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction and it seems that it's possible to do it. This brings up another question.. as usual. How does one install or obtain the JSON Handler class?

Comment: You don't need any classes, just few functions like `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()` in js and `json_decode()`, `json_encode()` in php.

Comment: Hi @AniketSahrawat. Does it send automatically? If I just JSON.stringify('activity') and next thing json_decode('activity'), just like that?

Comment: No, it will just convert the object to string. Whenever in doubt, just dump the variable to console / page and see what it outputs.

Comment: Okay.. Seems you are a bit too advanced for me to completely follow.
How do I send it, then? Could you perhaps make an example how to transfer a single string from javascript to php within an .php file?

Comment: Here is an excellent post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750661/send-json-object-from-javascript-to-php

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Thanks for that.